# Using imagemagick montage with PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to make a montage using imagemagick. I get it to work partially. I want to make a montage 2 columns by 2 rows. With 5px of padding between images, on a white background. When I use the following code the resulting image is twice as high and twice as wide as one image although only the first of four images appear in its correct size and spot, with white in the remaining three spots. All images are the same dimensions and same filetype.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$loc1 = 'http://localhost:8888/gallery_edited/0116.jpg';
$loc2 = 'http://localhost:8888/gallery_edited/0115.jpg';
$loc3 = 'http://localhost:8888/gallery_edited/0114.jpg';
$loc4 = 'http://localhost:8888/gallery_edited/0113.jpg';
$image = new Imagick("$loc1 $loc2 $loc3 $loc4");
$image -> setFormat("jpg");
$image = $image -> montageImage(new ImagickDraw, '2x2', '600x400', 0, '0');
echo $image;
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [Imagick::addImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.addimage.php) to build the image stack with new instances of Imagick object.

```php
<?php

$sources = array(
    'red.png',
    'green.png',
    'blue.png',
    'orange.png'
);

$stack = new Imagick();
foreach( $sources as $source ) {
    $stack->addImage(new Imagick($source));
}

$montage = $stack->montageImage(new ImagickDraw(), '2x2', '500x300', 0, '0');
$montage->writeImage('out.png');
```

[image: montage with php example]

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been thinking it must not be using all the sources.

Comment: I had to change `$stack->addImage(new Imagick($source));` for `$stack->addImage($source);` as the class Imagick was already created before. Without changing that it didn't work, at least for me.